# AX 2012 Command prompt compilation / AxBuild.exe for Parallel Compile on AOS of X++ to p-code

Tags: dynamic, compilation, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Is there any proper documentation on how I can use the axbuild.exe command in cmd with proper steps. All I know it is a quick way to compile the AX but how it works I don't know. Also, my compilation from the default AX environment takes hours on compilation so this will be a good option to use.
I know we have to use

```
axbuild.exe  xppcompileall  /s=01 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\bin
```

But how it is used I don't know. Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below blog explain every single step to perform parallel compilation in ax 2012 :

> [AxBuild.exe for Parallel Compile on AOS](https://360dynamics.blogspot.dk/2017/10/using-axbuild-command-for-parallel.html)

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN documentation is very clear. I would start here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528954.aspx

Also, there are some good comments at the very bottom of the article.